# Retrieve Record in CRM 2015 using CRMRestKit

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I have use imported CRMRestKit (version 2.6.1) library including JSon2 and Jquery(version 2.1.1).

Here is part of code.
    **CrmRestKit.Retrieve("vwfm_company", companyLookup[0].id, ['']);**

It do not return any record although there is a match.
Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried adding the columns you are expecting? CRMRestKit does an explicit select on the columns you provide in that last parameter.

Comment: i use collection to retrieve the column. Checking its collection.Length, it is zero.

Comment: After tried adding the columns (make sure there is no typo..!), it is work..! :)

Comment: I've added the answer for others to reference

Answer (score 0):

You should add the columns you are needing as the last parameter in your function call.

CRMRestKit does an explicit select on the columns you provide in that last parameter.